# How do I set a looping video as a background and play another video on top of it as a header. I also want to add buttons over the background

Tags: html, css

My question is straightforward but the answer seems to be complex. I have a video, say Video1, and I set it as my background (which covers the entire page leaving no margin or border. For the header (I'm using my second video, Video2, here as a video header), I plan on adding a second video which plays on top of the first one. Both videos play together. I also want to add some buttons over the background video. Could someone please help me figure out how to do this???

Comment: Please add the code you have tried already - SO doesn't provide an ab initio coding service but people are happy to help where they can see you have got stuck in your coding. This link will help you with adding your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using APNG images if the videos have no sound and assuming the buttons aren't playback controls. APNG images support 32bit color unlike GIFs.

Comment: so instead of rendering my files as MP4s, I render them as APNGs??

Comment: but aren't APNG animations a lot less fluid and smooth???

Comment: I see no reason to convert from MP4s or other video formats to images. It is perfectly possible to use a video in an element covering the whole viewport (use object-fit cover)